# How to set Tlsv1.2 in soap APi Java

Tags: java

I am creating Soap Request using soap Api java .my code looks like .

```
/**
 * Used to create dummy request for the SOAP operation
 * 
 * @param operationName
 * @param wsdlPath
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
private Document generateRequestBody(String operationName, String wsdlPath) throws Exception {
    WsdlOperation operation = null;
    String request = null;
    Document document = null;
    if (null == this.wsdl) {
        // Creating WsdlProject Object to load the wsdl using SOAPUI API
        WsdlProject wsdlProject = new WsdlProject();
        appLog.info("wsdlProject" + wsdlProject);
        appLog.info("wsdlPath" + wsdlPath);
        try {
            //WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(wsdlProject, wsdlPath,true);
            WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(wsdlProject, wsdlPath);
            wsdl = wsdls[0];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            appLog.debug("Error got", e);
        }
    }
    if (null != wsdl) {
        operation = wsdl.getOperationByName(operationName);
    }
    request = operation.createRequest(true);
    // Converting the request content into XML document
    document = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(request)));
    return document;
}
```

here my wsdl with Url Https are not getting loaded as my server is TLSv1.2 enforced . so i getting the below exception

> Failed to load url [https://82.150.238.5:5044/sst/SambaCustomerPreferenceService.http.ssl.v1-4-0-0?WSDL]>
>
> <> <> <> <1500268274375>  <05:11:14,375 ERROR
>   [SoapUI] An error occured
>   [com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.InvalidDefinitionException],
>   see error log for details> 
>       ####     
>   <> <> <> <1500268274375>

Please tell how to set `TLSV1.2` in Soap Ui code.

Comment: You should share most important part of error log here. The link provided by you is not accessible for me... I suggest you describe more details.

Comment: Failed to load url [https://82.150.238.5:5044/sst/SambaCustomerPreferenceService.http.ssl.v1-4-0-0?WSDL]>

<> <> <> <1500268274375> <05:11:14,375 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occured [com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.InvalidDefinitionException], see error log for details> #### <> <> <> <1500268274375>..

Comment: I am getting this issue only when i m trying to load wsdl from secure channel (Https) using soap api java. Http is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge error can be solved by some below solutions.

1. Check the URL of the WSDL in a browser. Does it open? If not, your server is not started and the WSDL contract is unreachable.
2. Make sure you are not using a proxy and you don't have some proxy option set in the SOAP UI preferences
3. problem with the validity of your WSDL, but it is impossible to tell without checking it.

Comment: Wsdl is fine it is working with Http . only issue with https . Wsdl is getting opened in browser . i m using Soap Ui java Api to create request  so how it matters to check soap ui preferences for Proxy.